# Memory Usage of Windows CE Devices

Tags: windows, memory, memory-management

Is there any tools to measure memory usage of devices running Windows CE that don't require Platform Builder?

Comment: Almost any of the Task Manager apps for Windows Mobile will tell you that.

Answer (score 2):

There is a commercial tool called [Soti Pocket Controller](http://www.soti.net/PCPro/) that allows you to inspect memory usage, cpu usage, windows registry etc from your desktop workstation by using either a network connection or Active Sync.

Answer (score 0):

Entrek is quite a good tool. Have a look at it.
http://www.entrek.com/